# Auth0 PasswordLess - Give user both email and sms authentication options in lock 11

Tags: auth0

Could not find a solution in the auth0 docs.

When calling the new Auth0LockPasswordless API, the default passwordless option is 'email', unless it is specified with allowedConnections: ['sms'].

How would i enable both sms and email? I have enabled both in the auth0 settings page but find that only one or the other will display in the lock popup modal?

The docs seem to say that it defaults to email, unless speficied.

I tried using allowedConnections: ['sms','email'] and in this case it only shows the latter email passwordless option.

Thank you

Rishi

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for the sake of providing closure, I can tell you that at the time Auth0 Lock Passwordless doesn't offer the possibility to use both email and SMS at the same time.

If you wanted to use both, you would need to create your custom UI by using our [JS SDK](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js).

[Source](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/faq#q-can-i-offer-both-email-and-sms-options-at-the-same-time-)